# Twitter json count limit?

Tags: json, twitter

I was wondering if there is a limit to the number of tweets you can return as json using the api URL? eg. http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=false&screen_name=CocaCola&count=3000

Answer (score 0):

I think the V1.1 really have the limited.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Count(Optional):
Specifies the number of tweets to try and retrieve, up to a maximum of 200 per distinct request. The value of count is best thought of as a limit to the number of tweets to return because suspended or deleted content is removed after the count has been applied. We include retweets in the count, even if include_rts is not supplied. It is recommended you always send include_rts=1 when using this API method.